# PLSQL- Walking thru JSON structure without knowing element names

Tags: json, oracle, plsql

**Used Database:**
Im using Oracle 19c database, so i tried to use JSON functions declared already in PLSQL (for instance JSON_TABLE) to import JSON inside database table.

**What im doing:**

Im just calling API, getting JSON from it, and then i would like to import data inside the database, regardless of what data, and in what structure they came.

**Problem:**

I would like to iterate JSON data without knowing element names inside that JSON.
I would like to know where im actually am (name of current node), and names of child elements, so i could dynamically create tables from those names, add relations between them, and import all data.

**What i have tried:**

So far i was doing it manually- i had to create tables by myself. Importing data required knowledge of object names, and also knowledge of JSON structure that i want to import. And its working, but oh well... i would like to create something more universal. All this stuff had to be done, because i dont know any way to walk thru structure of JSON without knowing names of objects and generally- entire JSON structure.

Any ideas how to walk thru json structure, without knowing object names and relations between them?

Comment: You may think that after finding a way to traverse JSON tree and generate tables from it yol'll be done, but stored data has no any value if no one uses this data. Then another question arises: how would consumer know the structure of the data? Relational tables designed as static objects with predefined structure. If you need to store some unstructured data, then [store original JSON](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adjsn/creating-a-table-with-a-json-column.html#GUID-E6CC0DCF-3D72-41EF-ACA4-B3BF54EE3CA0). Or describe the overall goal you want to achieve.

Comment: @astentx 'stored data has no any value if no one uses this data'- it's easier to find out what is coming in that json in tabelarized form (for instance: customer would have possibility to aggregate data with common sql functions). Customer could also make a report from that easily, what is harder to achieve when we store original JSON in database. And ofcourse in some cases created tables might be not that usefull, as when developer would create them according to documentation., but in some cases I could save a lot of time, and customer wouldnt have to wait for the first visible effect.

Comment: So there are a lot of substeps to perform: 1) get top-level element and generate unique identifier for it (to build a relationship) 2) get JSON structure; 3) generate a table name to insert into or get existing table name from the collection of generated names (depending on the property path and type); 4) check if table structure has to be extended/altered (for **the simplest** case where each property has the same datatype across all objects); do not forget about column for generated identifier! this is **not an actual table**, but internal representation of the table definition

Comment: 5) compare current internal "table" structure with the actual database table structure to generate `create/alter` statements; 6) insert the data into the table providing only matching columns/attributes for the current object, its unique identifier and parent's identifier; 7) perform recursive call for each structured element (array, object) passing the generated identifier of the parent object and full path of parent object (to generate a table name). This is a very breaf structure of what should be done and it is of course too much for a single question. This is a complex task

Comment: To build a structure of your JSON data you may use [`JSON_DATAGUIDE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/JSON_DATAGUIDE.html) aggregate function or iterative approach of [`JSON_ELEMENT_T`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/json-types.html#GUID-BDE10AAA-445B-47B5-8A39-D86C8EA99283) with calls to `is_[scalar|object|array]`,  `get_keys` and `get_type`

Comment: @astentx that is exactly what i was looking for (get_keys/get_type). Seems like it can work that way. Gonna give it a try, thank you in advance.

Comment: @astentx it worked, you can put it as an answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn the new PL/SQL JSON data structures [JSON Data Structures](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/json-types.html#GUID-BDE10AAA-445B-47B5-8A39-D86C8EA99283)

```
procedure parse_json(p_json in blob) is
  l_elem json_element_t := json_element_t.parse(p_json);
  l_obj json_object_t;
  l_arr json_array_t;
  l_keys json_key_list;
begin
  case
    when l_elem.is_Object then 
      l_obj := treat(l_elem as json_object_t);
      l_keys := l_obj.get_Keys;
      for i in 1..l_keys.count loop
        //work with the keys
        if l_obj.get(l_keys(i)).is_object then
          // this key is object,
        end if;
        if l_obj.get(l_keys(i)).is_array then
          // this key is array, 
        end if;
      end loop;
    when l_elem.is_Array then
      l_arr := treat(l_elem as json_array_t);
      for i in 0..l_arr.get_size - 1 loop
        // work with array
        case l_arr..get_type(i) 
          when 'SCALAR' then
             if l_arr.get(i).is_string then
             if l_arr.get(i).is_number then
             if l_arr.get(i).is_timestamp then
             if l_arr.get(i).is_boolean then
          .....
          when 'OBJECT' then 
            ....
          when 'ARRAY' then
            ....
          end case;
      end loop;
    end case; 
end parse_json;
```

You can also use the truly helpful [JSON Data Guide and the DBMS_JSON](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adjsn/json-dataguide.html#GUID-219FC30E-89A7-4189-BC36-7B961A24067C) package to map out the json object for you and even automatically create a view using JSON_TABLE.

Regards

Comment: That is more or less what i was looking for.
Thank you.